# how to upload Php code into sub-domain using filezilla

Tags: php, ftp, subdomain, sftp, filezilla

how to upload Php code into sub-domain using filezilla...

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try a search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub Domains are normally mapped to a folder under your mail domains folder (if hosted server). If it's your own server it can be almost anywhere. Just find the folder and upload to it.

Answer (score 2):

A subdomain is only a DNS record that points to a different server or location. You should be able to just connect to the FTP server wherever the subdomain points and upload as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload using your main domain. However, you should upload the file to the directory which you use as the subdomain on your server.

To upload to subdomain.domain.tld

Upload connection = domain.tld

Upload into domain.tld/subdomain

This will put your files into your subdomain